# Run script through selection menu and see its output in ksh

Tags: shell, ksh

I've created a simple selection menu in ksh:

```
#!/bin/ksh
while :
do
clear
print "\t    Script Runner "
print "\tOptions:"
print "\t---------------------------------------------"
print "\t1) Run script 1"
print "\tEnter your selection: \b\c"
read selection
case $selection in
    1)  print
        print "\tYou selected to run script1"
        ./some_script
        ;;
esac
done
```

Is there a way to display the whole output from the script that was executed? I want to see if script has been executed correctly or if it crashed.

Comment: Play with `set -x` or `set -v` to display commands being executed and `set -` to turn of those verbose lines.

Comment: Hi, thank You for Your hint. When I put `set -x` in my script i see all the output of the whole script but not the way I wantet it. Script prints all the lines starting with +print, then the output from print etc. I've tried to put the `set -x` both at the beginning of the script and also in `case` but the output is the same

Answer (score 1):

In this case it is better to use `sleep #` after each selected option. Sleep will display all the output from the script that is executed and will wait for # seconds before clearing the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with the `print` function. Replace each `print` by `echo` for printing something to your screen. Even better is `printf "%s\n" something`, but first get your echo working.
EDIT: And add a line `read -p "hit any key to continue" dummy` just before done, since the next loop starts with `clear`.